# Jquery post data on same PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, post

I wanted to post data using jquery and pass it to PHP variable in same PHP file/page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.return_type').click(function(){
            ret = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:1000/globe/retrackView.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ret: ret},
            success : function(results){
                alert(results);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

But when I alert the result its alert the whole HTML tags.

```
$_POST["ret"];
```

and `$_POST["ret"]` is null

There's something that I need to revise in my syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is ". return_type" a button, checkbox?

Comment: return_type is textbox

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do. can you explain with little bit more details. like what are you trying to do exactly, some php code.

Comment: Share PHP/HTML code ?

Comment: I want to pass the data using javascript to php variable

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, ".return_type" you have used for textbox. So you should use change() instead of click() to bind events. If you use click event on textbox, it will immediately get called on click(without any value).

Comment: Try replacing "ret = $(this).val();" with "ret = $('.return_type').val();". Try alert(ret) and check whether you are getting text value or tag

Answer (score 0):

use change event instead of click as return_type as its textbox.

```
$('.return_type').change(function(){
            ret = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:1000/globe/retrackView.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ret: ret},
            success : function(results){
                alert(results);
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: still it cannot pass to $_POST["ret"]